# MFC: Cannot put convert std::string to LPWSTR into a function

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm writing a MFC project by Visual Studio 2015, character set config to "Use Unicode Character set"

I need to convert from `std::string` to `LPWSTR` to use with some MFC object properties like `LVITEM::pszText` in `CListCtrl`, `AfxMessageBox`, ... So I use this snipset from internet:

```
String str = "Hello world!";
std::wstring wname(str.begin(), str.end());
LPWSTR lStr = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wname.c_str());
MessageBox(lStr);
```

This approach work fine. But the problem is that every time I need to convert I must rewrite these statement, and I put this snipset into a function:

```
LPWSTR convertLPWSTR(std::string &str) {
    std::wstring wname(str.begin(), str.end());
    return const_cast<wchar_t*>(wname.c_str());
}
/...
String str = "Hello world!";
LPWSTR lStr = convertLPWSTR(str);
MessageBox(lStr);
```

But the message box output an error string (like error font)
:

Any one know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27296/6460438 )

Comment: A few notes on your implementation: `1` It seems that the habit to construct a wide character string from a narrow character string by simply widening the data type (completely ignoring the character **encoding**) is hard to kill. Stop doing it. It does not work as you expect. `2` Your `convertLPWSTR` implementation returns a pointer to a local object. That's undefined behavior. `3` The solution is trivially easy: `MessageBox(CString(str.c_str()));`

Comment: Do you know what `wstring`, `LPWSTR`, `c_str` do or are you programming by trial and error?

Comment: @Greg: That answer is needlessly complex. In MFC there is the [CStringT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) class template, that provides all the conversion c'tors you would ever need. And since you can pass a `CString` anywhere a C-style string is expected (including variable argument lists), it is really all you need.

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use

```
CString str = _T("Hello world!") ;
```

Comment: This does not convert from `std::string` (in case you wonder about the downvote).

Comment: The question isn't *"Should I be using `std::string`?"*. The question is *"I have a `std::string` and need to convert to a wide character string. How do I do that?"* Any way, I should really stop leaving comments, explaining why I downvoted an answer. It always leads to explaining it twice.